# How can I prevent the Powershell Invoke-sqlcmd truncating output at 80 columns?

Tags: powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

[image: e]In Powershell, Invoke-sqlcmd is truncating my output at 80 columns

I've tried this code and things are still being truncated at the 80th column

```
$ans=Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sqlServer -Database $MyDbName -Query $SQLSCRIPT -OutputAs DataTables |Format-Table -Property * -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096 | Out-File $FullPathReportFileName
```

How can I keep it from truncating and looking like this?:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the output look like?  The way it looks on the screen is kind of an illusion.  If you pipe to format-list, or select -expand property, it will probably show the whole thing.  You might like this setting:

```
$formatenumerationlimit = 99
```

Or increase the size of the window.

Comment: Just added a pic to the question

Comment: What version of powershell is it?  You can try piping it to ft -autosize, or increasing the width of the window.

Comment: So, I ran it with a larger powershell window and it worked fine.  It's strange that it's based on the width of the PS window.

Comment: `$FormatEnumerationLimit`, which defaults to `4`, determines how many elements of a _collection-valued property_ to display inside a column, which is unrelated to @cashonly's problem. It is worth making it clearer in the answer that increasing the size of the window is what helped.